# How to download and parse JSON with OperationQueue in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsoperationqueue

I have gotten stuck on a conceptually simple problem. What's happening is that the parse operation is executing before the downloading operation's completion handler finishes. As a result there is no data to parse. You can drop the following code right into a file and run it.

How do i make sure downloading completes before the parse operation runs?

```
import UIKit

let search = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=butter&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY"

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fetch = FetchNBDNumbersOperation()
        let parse = NDBParseOperation()

        // 1
        let adapter = BlockOperation() { [unowned parse, unowned fetch] in
            parse.data = fetch.data
        }

        // 2
        adapter.addDependency(fetch)
        parse.addDependency(adapter)

        // 3
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.addOperations([fetch, parse, adapter], waitUntilFinished: true)
    }
}

class FetchNBDNumbersOperation: Operation {

    var data: Data?

    override func main() {
        let url = URL(string: search)!
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (jsonData, response, error) in
            guard let jsonData = jsonData, let response = response else {
                debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.data = jsonData
            print("Response URL: \(String(describing: response.url?.absoluteString))")
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

class NDBParseOperation: Operation {

    var data: Data?
    var nbdNumbers = [NBDNumber]()

    override func main() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            guard let jsonData = self.data else {
                fatalError("No Data")
            }
            let dictionary = try decoder.decode( [String: USDAFoodSearch].self, from: jsonData )
            for (_, foodlist) in dictionary {
                for food in foodlist.item {
                    print("\(food.name) \(food.ndbno) \(food.group)")
                    let nbdNumber = NBDNumber(name: food.name, nbdNo: food.ndbno)
                    nbdNumbers.append(nbdNumber)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

struct NBDNumber {
    var name: String
    var nbdNo: String
}

struct USDAFoodSearch: Decodable {
    let q: String
    let sr: String
    let ds: String
    let start: Int
    let end: Int
    let total: Int
    let group: String
    let sort: String
    let item: [USDAFood]

    struct USDAFood: Decodable {
        let offset: Int     //Position in Array
        let group: String
        let name: String
        let ndbno: String
        let ds: String
    }
}
```

Comment: In my humble opinion I think you should redesign this to include only **one** operation that includes the 'fetch' and the 'parsing'. So when you are finished fetching the data then parse through the data, no need to have a separate operation for both because they are both relevant to each other anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer. Subclass Fetch Operation with the class below. And the tell it the operation is completed at the end of the Fetch Op completion handler.

```
class FetchNBDNumbersOperation: AsynchronousOperation {

    var data: Data?

    override func main() {
        super.main()

        let url = URL(string: search)!
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (jsonData, response, error) in
            guard let jsonData = jsonData, let response = response else {
                debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.data = jsonData
            print("Response URL: \(String(describing: response.url?.absoluteString))")
            self.state = .finished
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Found the Asynchronous Subclass here: https://gist.github.com/Sorix/57bc3295dc001434fe08acbb053ed2bc

```
/// Subclass of `Operation` that add support of asynchronous operations.
/// ## How to use:
/// 1. Call `super.main()` when override `main` method, call `super.start()` when override `start` method.
/// 2. When operation is finished or cancelled set `self.state = .finished`
class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }
    override var isExecuting: Bool { return state == .executing }
    override var isFinished: Bool { return state == .finished }

    var state = State.ready {
        willSet {
            willChangeValue(forKey: state.keyPath)
            willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.keyPath)
        }
        didSet {
            didChangeValue(forKey: state.keyPath)
            didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.keyPath)
        }
    }

    enum State: String {
        case ready = "Ready"
        case executing = "Executing"
        case finished = "Finished"
        fileprivate var keyPath: String { return "is" + self.rawValue }
    }

    override func start() {
        if self.isCancelled {
            state = .finished
        } else {
            state = .ready
            main()
        }
    }

    override func main() {
        if self.isCancelled {
            state = .finished
        } else {
            state = .executing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice solution however never call super.start() and you don't need super.main().  You don't actually do this in the code but have it in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your fetch operation, you resume the `URLSessionDataTask`. At this point, the operation thinks it's complete, because it doesn't know what's happening on other thread's and doesn't inherently care about concurrent operations, and it's dependent (`adapter`) starts. Meanwhile the `URLSessionDataTask` is still being executed on another thread.

From Apple's docs on `NSOperation`

> For non-concurrent operations, you typically override only one method:
>
> - `main()`

`URLSessionDataTask`s run concurrently, so you have do more work to wrap them in an `NSOperation`. In order to wrap concurrent operations you need to:

> ...override the following methods and properties at a minimum:
>
> `start()`
>
> `isAsynchronous`
>
> `isExecuting`
>
> `isFinished`

The `NSOperation` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) go into quite a bit of detail on this, but to summarize: you need to override `start()` instead of `main()` and have your implementation keep the operation status up to date.

Comment: Helpful clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are just using `main` method of operation queue.
And  you are not notifying operation queue about operation status

As **jjatie** `Operation Queue` needs a **isExecuting** and **isFinished** KVC to notify the queue about operation finished or executing

My suggestion to you is please read docs before go with such a complicated operations.

here is an example code

```
class WSOperations: Operation {

    private var _executing = false
    private var _finished = false
    private var showHUD:HUDFlag = .show

    override var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            return _executing
        } set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            _executing = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")

        }

    }

    override var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            return _finished
        } set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            _finished = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }



    override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            isFinished = true

            return
        }

        isExecuting = true

        func completeOperation() {
            isFinished = true
            isExecuting = false
            Logger.log(message: "Operation finished")
        }

        //Your request
           request =  DataManager.sharedManager.getRequest(showHUD: showHUD, success: { (success, response) in
                if let t = self.finishedBLock {
                    t.success(success, response)
                }
                completeOperation()
            }, failure: { (error) in
                if let t = self.finishedBLock {
                    t.failure(error)
                }
                completeOperation()

            })


    }
    override func cancel() {
        super.cancel()
        if isExecuting {
            isFinished = true
            isExecuting = false
        }

        request?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating this and don't even need to use an OperationQueue as the data task will be done asynchronously.

You can just do something like this:

```
class FetchAndParse {
    var data: Data?
    var nbdNumbers = [NBDNumber]()

    func fetch() {
        let url = URL(string: search)!
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (jsonData, response, error) in
            guard let jsonData = jsonData, let response = response else {
                debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.data = jsonData
            print("Response URL: \(String(describing: response.url?.absoluteString))")

            self.parse()
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }

    func parse() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            guard let jsonData = self.data else {
                fatalError("No Data")
            }
            let dictionary = try decoder.decode( [String: USDAFoodSearch].self, from: jsonData )
            for (_, foodlist) in dictionary {
                for food in foodlist.item {
                    print("\(food.name) \(food.ndbno) \(food.group)")
                    let nbdNumber = NBDNumber(name: food.name, nbdNo: food.ndbno)
                    nbdNumbers.append(nbdNumber)
                }
            }
            print ("Finished With \(nbdNumbers.count) Items")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Which you then use like this:

```
let fp = FetchAndParse()
print ("Before Fetch")
fp.fetch()
print ("After Fetch")
```

If you run that you will see the 'Before Fetch' and 'After Fetch' messages both display before the download and parse has finished and that the parse happens after the fetch correctly.

Of course you will probably need to update it so that the class informs something that everything is complete so maybe a completion handler or delegate but I will leave that up to you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion however Operations are required because there are other operations that depend on the first two and without them it will turn into an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: You should have mentioned that originally otherwise we are solving a problem with halve the information.